# Github Actions path does not update

Tags: c++, gcc, dockerfile, github-actions

Right now, I'm trying to build a tool from source and use it to build a C++ project. I'm able to extract the tar file (gcc-arm-none-eabi). But, when I try to add it to path (using `$GITHUB_PATH`, not `add-path`), the path doesn't apply on my next action and I can't build the file. The error states that it can't find the gcc-arm-none-eabi toolset, which means that it didn't go to path.

Here's the script for the entrypoint of the first function (make is ran in the next action to allow for path to apply)

```
echo "Downloading ARM Toolchain"
# The one from apt isn't updated so I have to build from source
curl -L https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-rm/10-2020q4/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2 -o gcc-arm-none-eabi.tar.bz2
tar -xjf gcc-arm-none-eabi.tar.bz2

echo "/github/workspace/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

I can't even debug by seeing what's in the path because running `echo $(PATH)` just says that PATH cannot be found. What should I do?

Comment: `echo $(PATH)` -> `echo "$PATH"`. There is no command `PATH`, there is variable `PATH`

Comment: It's likely `cat $GITHUB_PATH` to see the current path.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried doing that, but it just prints `/github/file_commands/add_path_8085e9a6-120d-46e6-ba89-aeaa06ec4f1a`. I also tried using `ls`, but it also prints `/github/file_commands/add_path_8085e9a6-120d-46e6-ba89-aeaa06ec4f1a`

Comment: FYI there is a GitHub action now for installing gcc-arm-none-eabi: https://github.com/carlosperate/arm-none-eabi-gcc-action

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I can't even debug by seeing what's in the path because running `echo $(PATH)` just says that PATH cannot be found. What should I do?

First, `PATH` is not a command so if you want to print its value, it would be something like `echo "${PATH}"` or `echo "$PATH"`

<s>Then, if you want to add a value to an existing environment variable, it would be something like</s>

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/github/workspace/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin"
```

EDIT: seems not a valid way to add something to the path using Github Actions, meanwhile it seems correct in the question. To get more details: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path . Thanks to Benjamin W. for pointing this out in the comments.

Finally I think it would be a better fit if you use a docker image that already contains that kind of dependancies (you could easily write your own Dockerfile if this image doesn't already exists). Github action is designed to use docker (or OCI containers) image that contains the dependancies you need to perform your build actions. You should take a look here: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/dockerfile-support-for-github-actions

Comment: I tried doing `echo "$PATH"` and I was able to see the path variable, thank you! I've attempted the `export` line, but sadly it still does not update the path. The path in the next action returns: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`.

Comment: I think GITHUB_PATH is actually the path to an executable because running `echo $GITHUB_PATH` returns this: `/github/file_commands/add_path_4d4c37d6-5051-40a5-9f91-34dba3008918`. It might be a directory too which I should check.

Comment: `export` is not how you add something to `PATH` in a GitHub Action; see [Adding a system path](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path). The way shown in the question is correct.

Comment: @Benjamin W. Thanks for pointing this out. I've edited my answer

Comment: Thank you, this ended up working! I'm facing a few more issues regarding the actual build cycle, but adding the command to my entrypoint file does add it to the path